# How to extract text to the left of the parenthesis with R?

Tags: r, regex

I have

```
String=“Text1.Text2(er2019).Text3(246)text.”
```

Desired output:

```
String=“Text2.Text3”
```

I want extract only `Text2`,  `Text3`,  - everything to the left of the `(` in the 2nd and 3rx elements. I am not interested in the first element `Text1`.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://adamspannbauer.github.io/2018/01/16/r-regex-tester-shiny-app/  Can you split the string on '.', giving you 3 pieces (stored in an array, perhaps). Then in each element, truncate at the '(', then join on '.' what's left of the 2nd and 3rd elements of the array? I doubt know r, but you could see if r has anything similar to JavaScript' `split` and `join ` functions. If Thu want to use regex for stripping the individual strings, look at regex101.com. It doesn't have r, but you could get close, then edit fir any subtleties in r's regex implementation. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
String <- 'Text1.Text2(er2019).Text3(246)text.'
Matches <- str_extract_all(string = String, pattern =  "\\.[^()]+\\(")[[1]]
Matches <- str_replace_all(string = Matches, pattern = "^\\.|\\($", replacement = "")
```

1. Using `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package we extracted all text located between a `.` and and `(`.
2. Using `str_replace_all` we removed each leading `.` and each trailing `(` from the extracted matches.

To get to your desired output, you can then paste all extracted matches collapsing with `.`, like this:

```
paste(Matches, collapse = ".")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
str = 'Text1.Text2(er2019).Text3(246)text.'
pat = '.*?\\.(.*?)\\(.*?\\)\\.(.*?)\\(.*'
substr =  '\\1\\.\\2'
sub(pat, substr, str)
```

The way I figured this out is by going to regex101.com and playing around until I got the results.  On regex101, I found that this pattern `.*?\.(.*?)\(.*?\)\.(.*?)\(.*` gave the result you want, but since R treats `\` as a special character, each `\` becomes `\\`.

You want to discard all the text up until and including the first period.
So all that text is captured by `.*?\\.`. The `?` makes that pattern stop at the first match, rather than the last match (called *lazy* matching).

Then we want to keep the text after that first period until the first `(`. 
`(.*?)\\(` assigned the text in between the `.` and the `(` to group 1. Putting `()` around a pattern creates a `capturing group` which you can use in your substitution.

We then discard the text in the parenthesis `\\(.*?\\)\\.`. And we repeat the pattern for group 2.